# Qt Iphone-like navigation Controller

Tags: qt, navigationcontroller

I'm new to Qt. This is simply great.
I was wondering whether you guys knew if there happened to exist some kind of navigation controller function like you can find on Iphone...

What I mean is I want to have one MainWindow and slide between different views.

What should I look for please ?

Any doc about that ?

Any help would be very much apreciated.

Thanks in advance and sorry for being such a noob... ;-)

Miky Mike

---

Me again, 
by searching the site, I've come across with this...

http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/Code_Example_for_SlidingStackedWidget_class_in_Qt

But is there a means of sliding with a mouse movement ?
This look more difficult to me...

Thanks,

Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Miky, in my understanding you're trying to write a mobile phone app using Qt (probably for a Nokia phone). I'd recommend you to have a look at [Qt Quick](http://qt.nokia.com/qtquick/) which is designed to help people develop mobile applications including touch screen input. You can find what you want there. Check out ListView and Flickable elements. With list view you can create much more than just a list view how we have seen it. You basically can flip whole pages horizontally and vertically which would be ListView items. If you develop for Symbian, check out [Qt Quick components for Symbian](http://labs.qt.nokia.com/2011/04/08/qt-quick-components-for-symbian-technology-preview/) where you may find necessary components.

Happy hacking !

Comment: Thank you Man ! But one more question... Can you use Qt Quick for developping windows and Mac applications as well. I mean, I have created an IPhone app but I would like to port it to Windows and and Symbian and Mac (though I guess it doesn't require much code to turn the Iphone app into an Mac app). Is it posssible ?

Comment: Well, good question ... Everything that you develop in QML will work on all platforms supported by Qt including Win and Mac. The point is if you want a mobile and desktop app to work "natively" on the target platform, you need to change the UI - use desktop elements for desktop and mobile for mobile. So probably you will have to change it in your app as well. QML Desktop Widgets is something very experimental and in initial stage now according to Nokia. So I think it will be hard to make use of desktop elements such as table, push button, tab bar, etc with QML on desktop at this point.